# javascript float number comparison

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I tried to do some sort of "random generator" - there are several adjacent points and depending on their brightness they are more or less likely to be chosen.

a point is an object with `x` and `y` coordinates and a `b`value, storing it's brightness.

my approach was to set a `p` object (`p` for possibility) which has a `start` and an `end` value (both something between 0 and 1) - the difference between the `start` and the `end` value depends on their brightness.

I then generate a random number and loop through all points to see, whether the random number is between their `start` and `end` property. As one points `start` value is the previous point's `end` value only one point should be chosen, but instead a random amount of points are chosen.

Thus I logged the random value and the points' `start` and `end` properties. Looks like everything worked, except that the following code

```
for (i = 0; i < numAdjacentPoints; i++) {
    // set some shorthands
    curr_point = adjacentPoints[i];
    // if there is no previous point, we start with 0
    prev_point = ((i === 0) ? {p: {end: 0}} : adjacentPoints[i-1]);
    // initiate a probability object
    curr_point.p = {};
    // set a start value (the start value is the previous point's end value)
    curr_point.p.start = prev_point.p.end;
    // set an end value (the start value + the point's brightness' share of totalBrightness)
    // -> points with higher darkness (255-b) are more have a higher share -> higher probability to get grown on
    curr_point.p.end   = curr_point.p.start + (255 - curr_point.b) / totalBrightness;
    // if the random value is between the current point's p values, it gets grown on
    if (curr_point.p.start < rand < curr_point.p.end) {
        // add the new point to the path array
        path[path.length] = curr_point;
        // set the point's brightness to white -> it won't come into range any more
        curr_point.b = 255;
        console.log("  we've got a winner! new point is at "+curr_point.x+":"+curr_point.y);
        console.log("  "+curr_point.p.start.toFixed(2)+" < "+rand.toFixed(2)+" < "+curr_point.p.end.toFixed(2));
    }
};
```

outputs this:

```
we've got a winner! new point is at 300:132 mycelium.php:269
0.56 < 0.53 < 0.67 mycelium.php:270
we've got a winner! new point is at 301:130 mycelium.php:269
0.67 < 0.53 < 0.78 mycelium.php:270
we've got a winner! new point is at 301:131 mycelium.php:269
0.78 < 0.53 < 0.89 mycelium.php:270
we've got a winner! new point is at 301:132 mycelium.php:269
0.89 < 0.53 < 1.00
```

--> WTF? `0.56 < 0.53 < 0.67`??

Comment: It is correct. 0.53 is bigger than 0.56 and is less than 0.67.

Comment: @Daniel Pereira 0.53 is bigger than 0.56? :/

Comment: `(0.56 < 0.53) < 0.67)` where the first operations equals false, and of course, *false* is less than 0.67 in javascript, false being sort of 0.

Comment: @pankar I think I need a rest...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
if (curr_point.p.start < rand  && rand < curr_point.p.end) {
```

instead of

```
if (curr_point.p.start < rand < curr_point.p.end) {
```

You were comparing a number with the result of a comparison, that is a boolean. Your code was equivalent to

```
if ((curr_point.p.start < rand) < curr_point.p.end) {
```

and as a boolean is converted to 1 or 0 when used in such an operation, you were testing

```
if (0 < 0.67) {
```

[operator precedence in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: thx!! you're my hero :D I didn't think I'd still make such stupid mistakes though D:

Comment: I don't know if that will comfort you but I had to read your test a few times before I saw it ;)

Comment: great write-up on operator precedence btw, thx a lot :) well, I wasn't sure anybody would read the code at all, so thx for doing it :D

Comment: This makes me wish every language implemented this the way Python does, but something with Javascript's crazy type conversions more so.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this:

```
if (curr_point.p.start < rand < curr_point.p.end)
```

Because `curr_point.p.start < rand` will be evaluated as a `boolean` and then, you'll have something you don't want:
`if (boolean < curr_point.p.end)`

The correct condition would be something like this:

```
if (curr_point.p.start < rand  && rand < curr_point.p.end)
```

In this case you'll have two booleans:
`if (boolean1 && boolean2)`
so you can compare them correctly.